# Inheriting generic abstract

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance, abstract

I'm not sure if this is possible at all, looking for some clarification.

I have a class structure like this:

```
public class FooBase
{
    //Some base class
}

public class BarBase
{
    //Some base class    
}

public class Foo : FooBase
{
    //Implementation
}

public class Bar : BarBase
{
    //Implementation
}

public abstract class FooBarHolderAbstract<T, V> where T: FooBase where V: BarBase
{
}

public class MyFooBarHolderImpl : FooBarHolderAbstract<Foo, Bar>
{
}

public class FooBarTest
{
    public void DoSomethingWithFooBar<T>() where T : FooBarHolderAbstract<FooBase, BarBase>
    {
        //Do something tith the obj
    }

    public void RunTest()
    {
        //This doesn't work, compiler says MyFooBarHolder is not convertible to FooBarHolderAbstract<FooBase, BarBase>
        DoSomethingWithFooBar<MyFooBarHolderImpl>();
    }
}
```

In the FooBarTest class, I'd like to create a method which accepts a generic parameter, which inherits from the abstract class having two generic parameters. The class MyFooBarHolderImpl extends the abstract base class and specifies its generic parameters with types which are inheriting from the abstract class' generic parameter types.

When I try to call this method (DoSomethingWithFooBar()) the compiler tells me that the type MyFooBarHolderImpl must be convertible to FooBarHolderAbstract

Is this something which cannot be done at all, or am I missing a concept/syntax?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @thebigbo: You're wrong on both fronts. Perhaps you're thinking of a different language?

Comment: big bo, you are wrong on both counts, this isn't c++

Comment: Yep. Sorry for the confusion. I thought it was c++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it can't be done directly - a `FooBarHolderAbstract<Foo, Bar>` *isn't* a `FooBarHolderAbstract<FooBase, BarBase>`. It's not clear whether or not you could *logically* have that, because we don't know what's in the abstract class.

You're basically looking for [generic covariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517), but that isn't supported on classes anyway - so you may want to introduce an interface:

```
public interface IFooBarHolder<out T, out V>
    where T: FooBase
    where V: BarBase
{
    // Define what you need in here
}

public abstract class FooBarHolderAbstract<T, V> : IFooBarHolder<T, V>
    where T : FooBase
    where V : BarBase
{

}
```

At that point, you can change `FooBarTest` to:

```
public void DoSomethingWithFooBar<T>() where T : IFooBarHolder<FooBase, BarBase>
{
    //Do something with the obj
}
```

... because an `IFooBarHolder<Foo, Bar>` *is* an `IFooBarHolder<FooBase, BarBase>`.

However, this only works if you can define all your operations for the interface which use `T` and `V` in "out" positions, e.g. return types from methods. If you ever need them in "input" positions, e.g. as method parameters, you're stuck - because a method expecting a `Foo` can't handle any other kind of `FooBase`.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my case I need the generics in input positions in some methods of IFooBarHolder, so something like 

void DoSomething(V param, int value);

So I cannot specify them as "out" position, therefore I'm stuck. I'll find a different approach, anyway, thanks for pointing this out, it helped a lot!

Comment: @AttilaBicskó: Another option would be to specify two type parameters - the T and V - to DoSomethingWithFooBar. It's hard to know whether or not that would help you.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying that and that's what @Dennis pointed out below, but that won't really help me, I'm trying to avoid the need of specifying generic parameters reduntantly.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't clear, what are you going to do in `DoSomethingWithFooBar`, since you don't pass any parameter, but here are another options:

```
public class FooBarTest
{
    public void DoSomethingWithFooBar<TFooBase, TBarBase>(FooBarHolderAbstract<TFooBase, TBarBase> obj) 
        where TFooBase : FooBase
        where TBarBase : BarBase
    {
        //Do something tith the obj
    }

    public void RunTest()
    {
        DoSomethingWithFooBar<Foo, Bar>(new MyFooBarHolderImpl());
    }
}
```

or

```
public class FooBarTest
{
    public void DoSomethingWithFooBar<TFooBase, TBarBase, THolder>() 
        where TFooBase : FooBase
        where TBarBase : BarBase
        where THolder : FooBarHolderAbstract<TFooBase, TBarBase>
    {
        //Do something tith the obj
    }

    public void RunTest()
    {
        DoSomethingWithFooBar<Foo, Bar, MyFooBarHolderImpl>();
    }
}
```

Comment: The first version won't work for me, because at the point where I want to pass in the generic parameter, I don't have an instance of it. The second version works, but that way I'll have to redundantly specify TFooBase and TBarBase when calling DoSomethingWithFooBar, and I wanted to avoid this, because I thought that MyFooBarHolderImpl already "knows" which childs of FooBase and BarBase is it implementing FooBarHolderAbstract with. Furthermore, in the real life scenario I actually have three generic params for FooBarHolderAbstract, so this ends up being kindof ugly. Thank you, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your `FooBarTest` as below. You have to define `T` for `DoSomethingWithFooBar<T>` as `FooBarHolderAbstract<Foo, Bar>`

```
    public class FooBarTest
    {
        public void DoSomethingWithFooBar<T>() where T : FooBarHolderAbstract<Foo, Bar>
        {
            //Do something tith the obj
        }

        public void RunTest()
        {                         
            DoSomethingWithFooBar<MyFooBarHolderImpl>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This can work, but I lose the main point of designing it that way. I'd like to call DoSomethingWithFooBar with generics which has generic parameters different then Foo and Bar, but inheriting from FooBase and BarBase.